# Is there a karaoke trainer for OS X? 

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, music

is there an easy-to-use karaoke training software for Mac OS X?
My point is, I select the .kar file (or the vocals-only .mp3) and I sing against, then I listen to what I've actually sang?

FWIW, I'm no professional singer. I'm a software developer, but singing is my hobby, so I seek utility to help me train myself singing...

Answer (score -1):

You could give [UltraStar Deluxe](http://ultrastardx.sourceforge.net/usdx-downloads/usdx/) a try:

> A free and open source karaoke game inspired by the Singstar™ game available on the Playstation®. It allows up to six players to sing along with music using microphones in order to score points, depending on the pitch of the voice and the rhythm of singing.

The content is somewhat limited though.

P.S. I'm thinking many usefull information could find out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraStar)

Comment: So are you recommending this application or not (as there are lot of problems with it)? A link to a website or such would help as well.

Comment: I would recommend to try UltraStar Deluxe (http://ultrastardx.sourceforge.net/usdx-downloads/usdx/)

Comment: there is also very interesting software called Performous http://performous.org/. I've tried to use last version (dmg) it works. I've tried to compile last version from source it does not work